# Specific fee in transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoinj

Is there any possible way to send transaction with specific fee (not fee per kb) from wallet in bitcoinj? Where should I look to find a solution :)? My code:

```
Address address = Address.fromBase58(BitcoinNetwork.mode.GetParams(), destAddress);
SendRequest req = SendRequest.to(address, Coin.valueOf(value));
completeTx(req);
```